# Show that if $Y$ has $E(Y)=μ,Var(Y)=σ^2$, and $P(|Y-μ|<σ)=0$, then $Y$ has the same distribution as $X$ described below for $k=1$

Tags: random-variable, standard-deviation, normalization, probability-inequalities

I'm having a hard time proving the second and third case of $X$:

Show that if $Y$ has $E(Y)=μ,Var(Y)=σ^2$, and $P(|Y-μ|<σ)=0$, then $Y$ has the same distribution as $X$ described below for $k=1$.
$$P(X=x)\begin{cases}
  \displaystyle \frac 1 {2k^2} & \text{ if }x=\mu+k\sigma \text{ or } \mu-k\sigma\\
  \displaystyle 1-\frac 1 {k^2} &\text{ if } x=\mu \\
  \displaystyle 0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

By the premise we know that:
$$^{(a):}P(|Y-μ|<σ)=1-P(|Y-μ|≥σ)$$
$$0=1-P(|Y-μ|≥σ)$$
$$P(|Y-μ|≥σ)=1$$
By Chebychev's Inequality for $k=1$
$$P(|Y-μ|≥(1)σ)=\frac 1 {(1)^2}\Rightarrow P(|Y-μ|≥kσ)=\frac 1 {k^2}$$
Let:
$$P(|Y-μ|≥kσ)=P(Y-μ≤-kσ)+P(Y-μ≥kσ)$$
$$=P(Y=μ-kσ)+P(μ+kσ<Y<μ-kσ)+P(Y=μ+kσ)$$
By symmetry we know that:
$$P(Y=μ-kσ)=P(Y=μ+kσ)$$
Let:
$$P(Y=μ-kσ)=P(Y=μ+kσ)=P(Y^*)$$
Such that, applying Chebychev Inequality:
$$^{(1):}\frac 1 {k^2} =2P(Y^* )+P(μ+kσ<Y<μ-kσ)$$
Let
$$^{(2):}P(|Y-μ|<kσ)=P(Y-μ<-kσ)+P(Y-μ>kσ)$$
$$=P(μ+kσ<Y<μ-kσ)$$
From the premise:
$$=P(μ+kσ<Y<μ-kσ)=0$$
Such that:
$$^{(1):} \frac 1 {k^2} =2P(Y^* )$$
And therefore
$$P(Y=μ-kσ)=P(Y=μ+kσ)= \frac 1 {2k^2}$$
Which is equal to the first case of the distribution.

Substituting (2) into (a) and applying Checbychev's Inequality for $k=1$ yields:
$$P(|Y-μ|<σ)=1-P(|Y-μ|≥σ)$$
$$⇒P(μ+kσ<Y<μ-kσ)= 1- \frac 1 {k^2} $$
I'm not sure how to conclude that for $P(Y=μ)=1- \frac 1 {k^2}$ and all other $P(Y=y)=0$?

Maybe something to do with $Var(Y)$...